# Executing 'where in' statement with Mysqljs\mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm using [mysqljs\mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql) in a Node application and I've run into some trouble performing statements with 'in' clauses.

Under paramater escaping, the documentation states that:

> Arrays are turned into list, e.g. ['a', 'b'] turns into 'a', 'b'

[Escaping query values](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values)

But when i try something like this:

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN (?)";
var params = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
console.log(mysql.format(sql, params));
```

I get a query containing only the first value of the array:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN ('a')"
```

Comment: If the doc isn't correct (never used it), an alternative would be to join the array, `params.join(',')`. But this should be done only if this is not possible with mysqljs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
var params = [['a', 'b', 'c']];
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Ebrahim. I'll accept when it's allowed in a couple of minutes.

Comment: @Stromgren, reading the SqlString code, I find that the function await an Array to put each cell on every ?, the doc say that if **a cell of this array** is an array, it will be converted like you want. This is why this response is working. Just for info ;)

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works, you could also try to write out the list items individually when formulating the statement (this should be automated). The resulting prepared statement would then look like:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE name IN (?, ?, ?)"
```